# Unity IOS Project Could not build module 'Foundation'

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, foundation, core-foundation

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l00F5.jpg) is the image detailing the issue. Unity developer here and I've been struggling to build my AR app to iOS. Working with arFoundation and arKit for this and I'm not quite sure what error is caused by. The Two main errors I'm getting are "Could not build module corefoundation" and Could not build module foundation".

Seems like the root because, but I've tried messing with embed frameworks and everything else, but nothing seems to work. Any help would great, thank you!